# Font Awesome trouble with fa-bed

Tags: font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome icons, the problem is that the size of `fa-bed` is 0X0 though the other icons are displayed properly.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 col_pad col_pad_xs">
        <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Flight</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 col_pad col_pad_xs">
        <i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Hotel</span>           
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 col_pad col_pad_xs">
        <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span>+</span>
        <i class="fa fa-bed" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <span style="margin-left: -5px;">Flight + Hotel
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-3 col_pad col_pad_xs">
        <i class="fa fa-sun-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>Holidays</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: looks perfectly fine, try refreshing your page and clearing your cache: `ctrl` + `shift` + `r`

Comment: Also, any particular reason you're using both the `minified` and normal version of Bootstrap?

Comment: Thanks. But after refreshing and clearing my cache nothing changed.

Comment: No, I just forgot to delete the normal version. Thanks for the note.

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy by any chance? The proxy might be blocking the `fa-bed` icon.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I took a screenshot of my LAN Settings http://imgur.com/a/vM3lE
and I check Mozilla, Opera, IE, Edge, Chrome. All the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148230/discussion-between-thedarkknight-and-madonna-remon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the version I used with font awesome was old. I downloaded the current version `font-awesome-4.7.0` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
class="fa fa-4x fa-bed"
```